# How to use Promise with yield in nodejs router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I tried to configure backend factory to obtain data using Amazon Products Api.

Here is the script I execute in nodejs:

```
var amazon = require('amazon-product-api');
var client = amazon.createClient({
    awsId: 'ID',
    awsSecret: 'sectret',
    awsTag: 'tag',
});

// SERVER
// var Promise = require('bluebird');
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router')();

router.get('/node/:index', function* () {
    this.body = yield client.browseNodeLookup({
        browseNodeId: this.params.index,
    });
});

router.get('/', function* (ctx, next) {
    var node = yield client.browseNodeLookup({
        browseNodeId: 1063498,
    });
    this.body = node;
});

var app = koa();
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(8005);
```

At the frontend I use Promise.map() by bluebird.js to map an array of amazon's product nodes. At the final of the function, I expect to transform links (strings) in the Array to objects (obtained by API).
Here is the function:

```
someFn(links) { // links is an array of node IDs
    return Promise.map(links, (link) => {
        var link = link;

        if (typeof link === "object" || level > 1) {
            return link;
        } else {
            return loadUrl({
                url: 'http://localhost:8005/node/'+link,
                action: 'json',
            }).then((res) => {
                if (isJSON(res)) {
                    return new Category(res); // transform string to object
                } else {
                    return link;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Amazon allows at max 10 queries, that's why I need to run the function a few times or loop it to obtain an object for the each string in the Array.

The idea is to wait for the successful answer at the backend or repeat the query (yield client.browseNodeLookup)
Or just pass the array of node IDs and get JSON of each as the result.

I have not a lot experience with nodejs server and routing configuration, so can you help me to configure it properly?

Comment: Backend script I think can be like:

Promise.map(this.params.index.split(','), function(node) {
    return yield client.browseNodeLookup({
        browseNodeId: this.params.index,
    })
}).then((json) => {
    this.body = json;
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still did not find the solution to use backend for the task, but I've updated a loadUrl function. The function runs itself until retrieved the successful answer:

```
function loadUrl(options) {
    var options = options;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.post('/', options).done((result) => {
            if (result != 'Internal Server Error') {
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                (function run(x) {
                    var x = x || 0;
                    // 300 - calls limit
                    // for me 100 is enough
                    if (x <= 300) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $.post('/', options).done((result) => {
                                if (result != 'Internal Server Error') {
                                    resolve(result);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('call', x);
                                    run(x+1);
                                }
                            });
                        }, 100);
                    } else {
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                })();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

As I understood, the $.post() has time limit for the answer, and thats why I've got the problem. The data is obtained by the backend factory, but my frontend script was not ready to wait for it and was stopped.

Comment: And moreover I've added to each Promise.map {concurrency: 500} before ).then(